# Why does ![](some_file.md){.epigraph} means \inludeGraphics(some_file)

Tags: formatting

I'm a newbie to latex, and I can't seem to understand some things like why when I use the command

```
pandoc test.txt --lua-filter=epigraph.lua --to latex > test.tex
```

it converts my `![](some_file.md){.epigraph}` in my .txt
to `\includegraphics(some_file)` in my .tex

Even though I don't use any type of graphic and all I want to do is insert text to a specific location.

Is it some kind of special formatting, and are there more of these?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about Pandoc's Markdown syntax and not about LaTeX.

Comment: The `![](...)` markdown syntax is to include an image ( so you obtain `\includegraphics` trying to load a wrong file type in LaTeX) and `[](...)` (without the `!`) is to include a link to a section label, a local file or an URL. In any case these codes  are to include external texts like the `\input` command in LaTeX.